# React Native getting blank white screen on app startup before splash

Tags: ios, react-native, splash-screen, react-native-ios

I have developed a basic react native app, which seems working fine in android OS, but in iOS, I am getting a weird issue, that is, getting a blank screen as soon as the app loads before the splash screen.

Here is my `index.js` file

```
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import App from './App';
import bgMessaging from './src/FCM/bgMessaging';
AppRegistry.registerComponent('payrollApp', () => App);
AppRegistry.registerHeadlessTask('RNFirebaseBackgroundMessage', () => bgMessaging);
```

I have also tried replacing the default xib (the welcome screen) with my splash screen, but in that case, still I am getting blank white screen between xib splash and react native splash.

I don't know, what exactly, I am missing, or what further modifications needed.

Comment: Have you seen if there are any errors in Metro Bundler or If you're using Simulator hit `cmd + D` and open the remote debugger. From there, open up the inspector (chrome) and see if there is an error there.

Comment: No errors. Though, when the blank white screen displays, meanwhile, on the top of the screen, it shows `downloading javascript bundle ... `.

Comment: Ahh, are you trying to build ios straight after building android js?

Comment: Not exactly, I have created the app especially for android OS first, then later I am modifying it to make it work on iOS as well, but getting this blank white screen on app load, in iOS.

Comment: Are you using XCode to build it? Is the bundle loading from `localhost`? In your metro bundle terminal window, do you see the bundle generate? (The green progress bar moving)

Comment: I have tried from XCode, and as well as from terminal through commands, and as well as tried to kill the app in iOS, and tried relaunching it.

Comment: Have you closed the Metro Bundler window (there should be a window with it in)? So the Javascript regenerates?